# May a member function template specialization have a different access level than the main template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

An answer to a [a question I had about deleting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028144/when-is-deleting-a-template-instantiation-preferable-to-deleting-a-non-template)  mentioned how member function templates can't be specialized at class scope. That led me to wonder if it's possible for a member function template specialization to have a different access level than the main template. In the code below, I'm trying to have a private specialization of a public member function template:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  template<typename T>
  void func(T) { std::cout << "Public\n"; }

private:
  template<>
  void func<char>(char) { std::cout << "Private\n"; }

  friend int main();
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.func(10);
  f.func('a');
}
```

With the latest MSVC, this compiles, runs, and produces the expected output:

```
Public
Private
```

With g++ 4.8 and Clang 3.2, the code is rejected. Clang says this:

```
error: explicit specialization of 'func' in class scope
void func<char>(char) { std::cout << "Private\n"; }
     ^
```

Presumably g++ and Clang are using 14.7.3/2 of C++11 as the basis for their behavior, but I think there might be a little wiggle room, because 3.3.6/3 says that the global scope is a namespace, and the global namespace (indirectly) encloses the template specialization.

My question isn't about these parts of the Standard or about any of these compilers' behaviors, though, it's about whether it is possible for a member function template to have a specialization that has a different access level than the general template. For example, is it possible to have a public member function template and a private specialization of that template?

Comment: If you try this with partial specialization of nested class templates, the behaviour of clang++ and g++ is even inconsistent: clang++ simply accepts the code, whereas g++ complains about a redeclaration with different access.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#44 strongly suggests that the intent is to **not** allow in-class specialization. And if it's not allowed, then there's no way to express a change in access level.

Comment: @dyp re: partial specializations, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#727 . Apparently, it's an unresolved issue.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Nice detective work (in both cases)!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The first one underlines that it currently is not allowed (so g++ and clang++ are correct rejecting the OP's code). The second one is about *explicit* specializations of class templates in class scope (which are still forbidden), my example was *partial* specializations (which are allowed) and different access specifiers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Write up your comment about CWG #44 as an answer, and I'll choose it.

Comment: My two cents. Although a SFINAE workaround is possible (as per [Yakk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk)'s [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21036735/1137388)) I would rather avoid this or, more generally, having overloads with different access control levels. (See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882352/how-to-make-a-parents-template-method-visible-from-a-child-class), especially [Angew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1782465/angew)'s comment and [Jan Hudec](http://stackoverflow.com/users/201725/jan-hudec)'s [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20882716/1137388).)

Answer (score 2):

We can always do it manually.

Some random SFINAE machinery:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> constexpr bool IsInt() { return std::is_same<T,int>::value; }
template<std::size_t>
struct SecretEnum {
  enum class hidden {};
};
template<bool b, int i=1> using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<b,typename SecretEnum<i>::hidden>::type;

class Foo {
public:
  template<typename T, EnableIf< !IsInt<T>(), 1 >...>
  void func(T) { std::cout << "Public\n"; }

private:
  template<typename T, EnableIf< IsInt<T>(), 2 >...>
  void func(T) { std::cout << "Private with int\n"; }

  friend int main();
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.func(10);
  f.func('a');
}
```

now this trick does not work with clang because of how I did the SFINAE and method distinguishing last I checked.  But that can be replaced with other similar tricks (like pointer based default arguments in the second argument -- replace `EnableIf< IsInt<T>(), 2 >...` with `EnableIf< IsInt<T>(), 2 >* = nullptr` or somesuch for clang.  I just find it less appealing.)

So what is going on above?  I have two different overloads for `func`.  Both are template functions with one argument that is a `T`, and a pack of some secret enum whose type is valid if and only if `T` matches the `IsInt<T>()` or `!IsInt<T>()` test respectively.  The type of the packs differ in the two cases (one if them is `SecretEnum<2>::hidden`, the other is `SecretEnum<1>::hidden`), so their signatures are sufficiently different to satisfy most C++11 compilers (clang considers them to be identical last I checked, generating errors, I believe clang is wrong).

When you invoke `func<blah>`, it checks to see which (if any) of the two `func` are appropriate.  As their conditions are exact opposites of each other, only one of them is ever the proper one.

In effect, we are doing manual specialization.

In C++1y, we may be able to `template<IsInt T>` and `template<IsNotInt T>` if the stars align properly and the concepts lite that gets into the technical report lets this work.

Comment: +1, because I agree that this gives the behavior my example requested, but even if low-cal concepts get added to a future standard, the technical answer to the question (based on the current standard) is apparently no. Even with concepts, there'd be two templates with differing access levels, not a general template with one access level and a specialization of that template with a different access level.